# Creating a fixed list of constants in pyomo: set, param or variable?

Tags: variables, parameters, set, pyomo

I am trying to make an array of fixed constants (model.oldweights) that I subtract from the variable x in this model, but I am getting an error:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.core.expr.numeric_expr import LinearExpression

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.nVars = pyo.Param(initialize=4)
model.N = pyo.RangeSet(model.nVars)
model.x = pyo.Var(model.N, within=pyo.Reals)

model.er = [1, 1, 3, 1]
model.oldweights = pyo.Param(model.N, initialize=[0,0,0,0])

model.linexp = LinearExpression(constant=0,linear_coefs=model.er,linear_vars=[model.x[i] for i in model.N])

model.c1 = pyo.Constraint(rule=sum(model.x[i] for i in model.N)==0)
model.c2 = pyo.Constraint(rule=sum(abs(model.x[i]) for i in model.N)==2)
model.c3 = pyo.Constraint(rule=sum(abs(model.x[i]-model.oldweights[i]) for i in model.N)<=0.03)


model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = model.linexp, sense = maximize)

results = SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='/content/ipopt').solve(model)
results.write()

ERROR:pyomo.core:Rule failed for Param 'oldweights' with index 0:
KeyError: "Index '0' is not valid for indexed component 'oldweights'"
```

I have tried to make the list as a set, param and variable and nothing works.

Comment: Note that `abs(x)` is non-differentiable and `sum(abs(x))==2` is non-convex. I would linearize and use binary variables to handle the non-convexity.

Comment: I don't follow, how would I do that? Doesn't the sum make it impossible?

Comment: Also that doesn't solve my problem of wanting to subtract an array of constants from an indexed variable and summing the absolute value of the results.

Comment: No. But that can be solved by reading https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Parameters.html. E.g.: `model.oldweights = pyo.Param(model.N, initialize={i:0 for i in model.N})` or `model.oldweights = pyo.Param(model.N, initialize=0)`.